# ARM Template update overwrites something in Azure Function to cause error "The function runtime is unable to start"

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-rm-template, azureportal

If I create a dotnet C# Azure Function web app via the Azure portal, I can (zip) publish my functions and all appears to work ok. If I navigate to the function in the portal, i can see the function.json that is created for me and everything appears to be running fine.

Then, based on our infrastructure as code principles, as part of our deployment pipeline in Azure Dev Ops, we execute an ARM template to update the Function App which has all the settings we have copied from the Function App in the portal.

After this template as run, when we navigate to the function in the portal we instead get:

```
Error:

The function runtime is unable to start.
Session Id: a3dd6ec59c9a459d947ef1ffbb9bf00b

Timestamp: 2020-01-04T23:31:08.741Z
```

and we don't see a Function.json. **However**, the function still appears to be working (!). if I look in the Kudu Host logs then there do not appear to be any errors, e.g.

```
2020-01-04T23:29:27.639 [Information] Starting JobHost
2020-01-04T23:29:27.641 [Information] Starting Host (HostId=dev-backend, InstanceId=b9a1e02b-faee-4a37-844c-412622583ff7, Version=2.0.12888.0, ProcessId=7440, AppDomainId=1, InDebugMode=True, InDiagnosticMode=False, FunctionsExtensionVersion=~2)
2020-01-04T23:29:27.670 [Information] Loading functions metadata
2020-01-04T23:29:27.699 [Information] 1 functions loaded
2020-01-04T23:29:27.860 [Information] Generating 1 job function(s)
2020-01-04T23:29:27.976 [Information] Found the following functions:
Consumer.Function.ConfigurationUpdated.ExecuteAsync
2020-01-04T23:29:28.097 [Information] Initializing function HTTP routes
No HTTP routes mapped
2020-01-04T23:29:28.105 [Information] Host initialized (449ms)
2020-01-04T23:29:28.459 [Information] Host started (810ms)
2020-01-04T23:29:28.459 [Information] Job host started
2020-01-04T23:29:33.474 [Information] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID 'e4e6f1cb6c07cd9bd67163acfe2dba75'.
```

I'm not sure what could be missing from the ARM template to cause this to break, or where else to look to find why the runtime doesn't start...or even if it's really working correctly at all.

The template I'm using is:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
  "name": "[variables('statisticsBackendContainer')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "kind": "functionapp",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "service": "statistics",
    "costCenter": "[parameters('costcentre')]",
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('servicePlan'))]": "Resource"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', variables('servicePlan'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('databaseServer'))]",
    "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('loggingStorageAccount'))]"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[variables('statisticsBackendContainer')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', variables('servicePlan'))]",
    "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
    "httpsOnly": true,
    "hostingEnvironment": "",
    "siteConfig": {
      "phpVersion": "off",
      "Use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
      "AlwaysOn": true,
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
          "connectionString": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('loggingStorageAccount'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('loggingStorageAccount')), '2016-01-01').keys[0].value)]",
          "type": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "AppSettings:apiSecret",
          "value": "[variables('apiSecret')]"
        },
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
          "value": "dotnet"
        },
        {
          "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
          "value": "~2"
        },
        {
          "name": "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY",
          "value": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/',variables('statisticsBackendContainer')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey]"
        }
      ],
      "connectionStrings": [
        {
          "name": "microsoft.servicebus.connectionstring",
          "connectionString": "[listkeys(variables('sendlistenServiceBusNamespace'), '2014-09-01').primaryConnectionString]",
          "type": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "statistics.connection",
          "connectionString": "[concat('Server=tcp:', reference(concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', variables('databaseServer'))).fullyQualifiedDomainName, ',1433;Database=', variables('databaseStatisticsName'), ';User Id=', parameters('appLogin'), '@', variables('serviceNameEnvironment'), ';Password=', parameters('appLoginPassword'), ';Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;')]",
          "type": 2
        },
        {
          "name": "logging.connection",
          "connectionString": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=', variables('loggingStorageAccount'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('loggingStorageAccount')), '2016-01-01').keys[0].value)]",
          "type": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "management.webhook",
          "connectionString": "[concat('https://',variables('managementApiContainer'),'.azurewebsites.net')]",
          "type": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: how are we supposed to know whats missing if you dont even share the template? or the function language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I think the ARM template was misleading as the AzureWebJobsStorage AppSetting was missing from the deployed Function app. When I made sure it was in the ARM template and redeployed then everything appears to work ok in the Azure portal.